# Swift 2 why is my custom UITableViewCell class not being applied?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on this app and for the moment I have 2 views:

- The main one which has a table view with several custom
  UITableViewCells I made - these work fine
- A second view that I use to show more specific data with another table view with 
  another custom UITableView that is NOT showing any of the elements I've set,       such as labels, buttons and text fields, nothing except a series of blank table cells

I've spend a few hours trying to figure out why the custom cells I made for the main view work and the ones for the second view do not, given the fact that I did exactly every step I did for the other ones like creating a new class with the .xib, assign the respective class to that .xib and set the correct identifier.

This is what I have inside my viewDidLoad method on the second view (the one I'm having problems with):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Número actual"

    //Celda articulos
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "articuloCelda", bundle: nil)
    articulosTabla.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "articulo")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    titulo.text = tituloTexto
    numero.text = numero.text! + " " + numeroTexto
    portada.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imagenUrl)!)

}
```

and this is the cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:articuloCelda = self.articulosTabla.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("articulo") as! articuloCelda

    return cell

}
```

I also tried to check if it was an autolayout issue, so I removed all the constraints, still the same, checked if by any chance the text color was white, and it was not, so since I've only been working with iOS and swift for about 2 weeks I find my self all out of ideas...

Maybe a pair of fresh eyes will point me in the right direction. Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: What value are you returning for `numberOfRowsInSection` in the problem case?

Comment: that would be the length of a JSON array, in this case that is 4 and that part works fine as I get 4 blank cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that you are calling the delegate and datasource on your UITableView

Comment: I totally forgot these things ever existed, thanks that solved the problem